# Android devices, ionic app and $cookies

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova, cookies, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a little mobile app with ionic and a wordpress (and JSON API) for backend.

I choose cookie auth for log people. This méthode work perfectly in my web browser thanks but when I use "phonegap serve" or apk directly on my phone nothing happen.

According to following lines $cookies.put(...) seems not working on my Android device.

```
console.log("Cookie: ");
$cookies.put(data['cookie_name'],data['cookie']);
console.log($cookies.getAll());
```

Have you some idea to resolve my problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use cookies, you should use localStorage.

To set the localstorage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

To retrieve localstorage:

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

To remove particular localstorage:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

To clear all localstorage:

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

For your reference, you can use [this](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/) link.

I am sure, this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for this first element. Now I can store my objects but I'm not able to use it. I fact when in try to add an value to cookie header I have this error: **Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"**

Comment: `$http({ method: 'GET',
   url: 'example.com',
   headers: {'Cookie': 'test'}, ....`

Comment: Have you referred link?

Comment: I have nothing for the moment I 'll try to create something in the day

Comment: Then please accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: ok, I'll do this when my question will be ok. At the moment i can't use cookie auth (the purpose of my question)